# Page based interface use multiple of the same viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I want to create a page based interface in WatchKit.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html) state that one has to create multiple interface controllers and link them to create a page based interface.

Imagine I have a few objects, and for each object I want to display info on the Watch. Then I want to use page based navigation to swipe to the next item. All items use the same interface controller, just with different data.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have associated the same InterfaceController for each of your page, to pass different data to each of the page follow undermentioned steps:

1. Create a initial view controller, which will act like a splash
   screen for your app.
2. In "willActivate" of initial view controller, create an array of
   pages and an array of contexts with the data that you need to pass
   to each of these pages(interfaceViewControllers).
3. Call WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(pages,
   contexts: pageContexts).
4. In "awakeWithContext" of your common InterfaceController for each of
   the pages, read the context and initialise properties/data.

Point no. 3 basically ensures that your pages are displayed as if directly launched. Other option you've is to use self.presentControllerWithNames, but that will show a "Cancel" button on top left.

Example Code:
In SplashScreen Interface Controller

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    let pages = ["page1","page2","page3","page4"]
    let pageContexts = [["data1":0,"data2":0],["data1":38,"data2":1],["data1":49,"data2":1],["data1":74,"data2":2]]
    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(pages, contexts: pageContexts)
}
```

In Page Interface Controller

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if let contextDict:Dictionary = context as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>!
    {
        data1 = contextDict["data1"] as Int
        data2 = contextDict["data2"] as NSTimeInterval
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, will try tomorrow. What I still don't know is what if the amount of items/pages changes, e.g. it can be 1,2 or 5. Then I could create 5 scenes linked to each other,  but how can I skip 3 when the actual amount of pages is just 2?

Comment: I think, you can use "self.becomeCurrentPage()" in this case.

Comment: Awesome. You actually do not need to make multiple of the same interfacecontrollers in storyboard. You can just add multiple of the same page identifiers to the pages array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define a static like below, putting reloadRootControllersWithNames in willActivate causes an infinite loop.

```
static BOOL first = YES;
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];

    if (first) {
        [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SinglePageICIdentifier",@"SinglePageICIdentifier", nil] contexts:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second", nil]];
        first = NO;
    }
}
```